# Custom Round Up in javascript

Tags: javascript, math

I'd like to round up a number like that:

```
roundup(number, 2)

Output
1.155 -> 1.16
1.0015 -> 1.01
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil - They even have examples showing exactly what you want. _(p.s. I managed to use google and find this in seconds)_

Comment: Math.round(1.0015 * 100) / 100

Comment: @FabioWidmer: Please try with your suggestion !

Comment: @evolutionxbox : Please try to practice with your link before comment !

Comment: Why would 1.15 become 1.20 if the second argument of your `roundup()` function is 2? That doesn't make sense alongside the other example of 1.0015 -> 1.01.

Comment: @nnnnnn: 2 is precision length

Comment: @nnnnnn: yeah, but I expect that result. May be round() will make more sense

Comment: OK, if 2 is the precision, then why didn't `1.0015` become `1.1`? Again, one or the other example doesn't make sense.

Comment: No, My business need to round the number like that. If the fractional part (0.0015) > 0.00 (precision 2 of zero), I want it round to the min value of precision (0.01)

Comment: @pcuong - did you know that in JS `0.1 + 0.2 !== 0.3`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: What do you want to prove?. Please read carefully my question. This is a custom round !

Comment: @pcuong - nothing. I've carefully read your question. Your example code is not consistent. The first is rounding up by 0.05 and the other is rounding up by 0.0005. Only the first example would be an output of the roundup function, not both. - (p.s. stop assuming we're against you)

Comment: @pcuong what does it mean "with min value"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
    var roundup = function(num, prec) {
      var magn = Math.pow(10, prec);
      return Math.ceil(num * magn) / magn;
    };

    /// e.g.
    roundup(1.155,2) // => 1.16
    roundup(1.0015,2) // => 1.01
```